# Component not shown in the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build basic app in react, and I don't understand why I can't see the info of one component (called instructions) in the DOM.
Anyone for help?

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import instructions from "./components/instructions/instructions"

class Generator extends React.Component {

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className="gen-button">
    <instructions />
    <button type="button">generate</button>
      </div>
      <div className="random-number"> 
      <p>0</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

And instructions component:

```
import React from "react";

const instructions = () => {

    return (
        <div>
        <p>Click "generate" for a random number"</p>
        </div>
        );
}

export default instructions;
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example in stack blitz or somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a first glance, everything seemed correct. However, after doing a double take I noticed that your `<instructions/>` component does not start with a capital letter, which is something that React expects of custom components...

As noted [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html#notable-bug-fixes)

> the JSX tag name convention (lowercase names refer to built-in components, capitalized names refer to custom components).

So if you change the `<instructions/>` to be `<Instructions />` (in the import, the call, the export and the creation) it will work as expected.

Please check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-dubinsky-tu7wd)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your `<instructions/>` component to  `<Instructions/>` , as per the JSX convention, only Capital is taken to consideration

Answer (score 0):

Components should start with a Capital. 
If you change 'instructions' to 'Instructions' it works.

See the code below (in an empty React-App)  App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const aaa = () => {
    return (
        <p>This is from 'aaa' component</p>
    )
}

const Bbb = () => {
    return (
        <p>This is from 'Bbb' component</p>
    )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <aaa/>
      <Bbb/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The output is:

```
This is from 'Bbb' component
```